# How can I evaluate this limit with complex exponentials?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{i\pi(1+\epsilon)} - e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}}{(1+\epsilon)^2 -1}$$

The only thing I have been able to simplify it to is

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{i\pi\epsilon}e^{i\pi} - e^{-i\pi\epsilon}e^{-i\pi}}{\epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon}$$

I dont know what would be the next steps from here. The answer should be approximated to $\frac{1}{2i}$  where $i = \sqrt-1$

Comment: Did you know that $e^{i \pi} = -1$?

Comment: @OriaGruber Thanks, but now I have it down to $$ \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{-2isin(\pi\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon}$$  which after using Lhoptial rule twice gives me 0

Comment: It should not be $0$. Your last expression can be written $\frac{-2\pi i}{2+\epsilon} \frac{\sin(\pi\epsilon)}{\pi\epsilon}$. The last factor has a finite limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $e^{i x} = \cos (x)+i\sin (x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor series: $e^{z} = 1+z + \frac{z^2}{2} +o(z^2)$ when $z\to 0$. (It also applies to $z\in\mathbb{C}$).

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{i\pi(1+\epsilon)} - e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}}{(1+\epsilon)^2 -1}
&= \frac{e^{i\pi}e^{i\pi\epsilon} - e^{-i\pi}e^{-i\pi\epsilon}}{(1+\epsilon)^2 -1} 
=  \frac{e^{i\pi}(1+ i\pi\epsilon + o(\epsilon)) - e^{-i\pi}(1-i\pi\epsilon+ o(\epsilon))}{(1+\epsilon)^2 -1} \\
&= \frac{-(1+ i\pi\epsilon ) + (1-i\pi\epsilon )+ o(\epsilon)}{1+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2 - 1} \\
&= \frac{- i\pi\epsilon -i\pi\epsilon + o(\epsilon)}{2\epsilon + o(\epsilon)}\\
&= \frac{-2i\pi\epsilon + o(\epsilon)}{2\epsilon + o(\epsilon)} = -i\pi + o(1)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{i\pi(1+\epsilon)} - e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}}{(1+\epsilon)^2 -1}=$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}\cdot \left(e^{(2i)\pi(\epsilon+1)}-1\right)}{\epsilon(\epsilon+2)}=$$
$$\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}}{\epsilon+2}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{(2i)\pi(\epsilon+1)}-1}{\epsilon}\right)=$$
$$\left(\frac{e^{-i\pi(1+0)}}{\epsilon+2}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{(2i)\pi(\epsilon+1)}-1}{\epsilon}\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{e^{(2i)\pi(\epsilon+1)}-1}{\epsilon}\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0} 2i\pi e^{2i\pi(\epsilon+1)}\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(2i\pi e^{2i\pi(0+1)}\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(2i\pi\right)=-i\pi$$